# TypeError: string indices must be integers django

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I want to know what kind of data should I send to `django-rest-framework` and dont get the string indices must be integers ?

the function is

```
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def update_interests(request): 
    user_profile = request.user.userprofile
    interests = request.data
    user_profile.interests.set(
            TopicTag.objects.get(name=interest['name'])[0] for interest in interests
    )
    user_profile.save()
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

the error is

```
typeError: string indices must be integers
```

and the data I have send is a json

```
{
    "name": ["news"]

}
```

just in case the models.py looks like this

```
class TopicTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

maybe you need the serializers so here you are

```
class TopicTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TopicTag
        fields = '__all__'
```

help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.data is a dictionary. which has the value as follows:

```
{
"name": ["news"]
}
```

when you are traversing it in your for loop it would return you keys of the dictionary in the iterator.
in this case:

```
"name"
```

now when you trying to access it like this

> interest["name"]

it returns an error because it expects an integer.

you can get names like this

```
request.data.get("name")
```

and in your query you can do something like this

```
TopicTag.objects.get(name=interest)
```